# Suggested architecture to re-render scene only if scene has changed?

Tags: three.js

I have a complex web application, with several sub-views / widgets that add objects to the main scene.

Most simple THREE.js examples have a continous render loop, that re-renders the scene periodically.
This seems like a waste of ressources to me.
Therfore, I only want to re-render the scene if something has changed.

However, the sub-views / widgets do change things (like position of objects) in the scene on their own.

Is there something like a "scene.hasChanged" flag, that I can use to deceide if the scene needs to be rerendered? Or do I have to implement a parallel flag or notification structure myself?
Or is there another common solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you have written so far, it seems you have to implement a custom solution. Certain `three.js` examples like [webgl_loader_gltf](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf) do not use an animation loop but utilize `change` events from the controls. The relevant line of code is

```
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

However, if more factors than just the user interaction trigger renderings, it's necessary to build some sort of notification/event system by yourself.

`three.js R113`